# How do "flux" and "redux" relate to "react native" and which of these should a new "react native" start using?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, flux, relay

How do "flux" and "redux" and "relay" relate to "react native" and which of these (flux and/or redux and/or relay) do most "react native" developers use.

Background: For someone starting up with "react native" which of these (i.e. flux, redux, relay) should they start aiming to utilise from day 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of them handles the state of your application they only differ on the complexity of setting them up. Relay is more complex I think, compare to flux and redux and when using relay you should be well aware of how GraphQL works.

You actually don't need to use any of this if your application is small. I would suggest getting your self comfortable with handling states on your component, then proceed on using one of this tools. (I personally use redux) setting up is cumbersome for new users but it pays off. I would also suggest checking out Mobx.

Comment: thanks - so you think build an initial app with "react native" + Mobx, then later can look to move to "react native" + Redux?   Or did you more mean consider using Mobx rather then Redux in general perhaps?

Comment: Mobx and Redux are pretty much the same. If your still practicing on using React Native, I would suggest using React Native without using any third party state manager just so you could familiarize your self with handling and manipulating your application state.

Comment: But if you really want to learn redux here's a free tutorial from the creator of redux him self https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: ok thanks - I was wondering if I didn't start with redux (if I was ultimately going to use it) I would have to "unlearn" the base 'react native' approach (if that make sense).   But sounds like this isn't an issue.